# docker - tomcat8 on centos 7

Tags: docker, centos, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to deploy a war to tomcat 8 on centos 7. I am getting the following error while deploying a war into the tomcat 8.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/plperl.so": /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/plperl.so: undefined symbol: errcontext
  Where: PL/pgSQL function db.c_scr(text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,date,date,character,character,boolean,boolean,text,character,text,text,character,text,character varying,text,text,boolean,text,text,boolean,character,text,text,text) line 1285 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:231) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:254) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.5.47]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:254) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.5.47]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:452) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:402) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
```

FROM centos:7
RUN ./initialize_env.sh

initialize_env.sh is as follows.

```
yum -y update && yum clean all
yum -y install unzip wget httpd httpd-devel gcc* make && yum clean all

# Install mod_jk
curl -SL https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz -o tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p src/tomcat-connectors \
    && tar xzf tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz -C src/tomcat-connectors --strip-components=1 \
    && cd src/tomcat-connectors/native/ \
    && ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs \
    && make \
    && cp apache-2.0/mod_jk.so /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/ \
    && ./libtool --finish /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/ \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf src/ \
    && rm -f tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz

echo "Downloading tomcat"
cd /apps/
wget http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.47/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.47.zip
unzip apache-tomcat-8.5.47.zip
mv apache-tomcat-8.5.47 tomcat
chmod -R 755 tomcat
chmod -R +x tomcat/bin
yum -y install postgresql-plperl
yum -y install java
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.3/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-3.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh pgdg-centos93-9.3-3.noarch.rpm 
yum -y install postgresql93 postgresql93-server postgresql93-libs postgresql93-contrib postgresql93-devel postgresql93-plperl
```

After this installation, i see this output.

```
sh-4.2# ls -l /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/plperl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 87304 Nov  7  2018 /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/plperl.so
```

I need to run Apache Web server with Tomcat. I have a postgres jdbc driver (version 9) under $tomcat_home/lib directory.  I even tried a higher version of jdbc driver, but it is still throwing the same error.

does anybody know why?

Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: try to connect in bash mode to your container with the following command : docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash and then execute : postgres --version  or execute command that should work if your postgresql is well installed. If error, then try to correct it directly in your container in order to find the cause, and what to change in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I am getting this postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24. but I am just trying to deploy a war file into the local tomcat. The war has its own configuration connecting to the remote postgres db. i don't know why it's looking for local db. is it related to the jdbc library which uses low-level code?